# XPATH: Sum on Child Node Not Whole XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

Real problem: I was using XPATH 1.0 with 2.0 syntax so the following wasn't working: `/root/row/checks[not(taxAmount = sum(selections/tax))]/sum(selections/tax/text())`

---

---

I have the following XPATH:

```
/root/row/checks[./taxAmount/text() != sum(./selections/tax/text())]/selections/tax/text()
```

I want something like the following:

```
/root/row/checks[./taxAmount/text() != sum(./selections/tax/text())]/sum(selections/tax/text())
```

I don't want to sum the entire statement, just the child nodes under /selections, but what I've tried so far results in syntax error

Essentially, I have check header information which isn't matching detail information and wanted to sum the detail to compare with the header.

Example XML:

```
<root>
  <row>
    <checks>
      <selections>       
        <tax>1.00</tax>
      </selections>
      <selections>       
        <tax>2.00</tax>
      </selections>
      <selections>       
        <tax>1.14</tax>
      </selections>
      <taxAmount>4.14</taxAmount>
    </checks>
    <checks>
      <selections>       
        <tax>1.00</tax>
      </selections>
      <selections>       
        <tax>0.50</tax>
      </selections>
      <selections>       
        <tax>1.00</tax>
      </selections>
      <taxAmount>3.00</taxAmount>
    </checks>
    <checks>
      <selections>       
        <tax>1.00</tax>
      </selections>
      <selections>       
        <tax>0.50</tax>
      </selections>
      <selections>       
        <tax>1.25</tax>
      </selections>
      <taxAmount>5.00</taxAmount>
    </checks>
  </row>
 </root>
```

Edit based on Daniel's answer:

That's not quite what I was looking for. That will select the checks with issues, but I wanted something like this:

/root/row/checks[not(taxAmount = sum(selections/tax))]/taxAmount/text()

3.00

5.00

/root/row/checks[not(taxAmount = sum(selections/tax))]/sum(selections/tax/text())

2.50

2.75

Comment: Could you show us a sample of your XML doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Essentially, I have check header information which isn't matching
>   detail information and wanted to sum the detail to compare with the
>   header.

If you're just trying to identify `checks` where the sum of `selections/tax` doesn't equal `taxAmount`, you can use:

```
/root/row/checks[not(taxAmount = sum(selections/tax))]
```

Based on your sample input, this would select the second `checks` element.

To output both the `taxAmount` and sum of `selections/tax`, you can use the following (XPath 2.0):

```
/root/row/checks[not(taxAmount = sum(selections/tax))]/concat(taxAmount,' ',sum(selections/tax))
```

this would output `3.00 2.5` using your sample input.

Comment: Updated my post based on your answer.

Comment: I was on XPath 1.0 and that's why the last sum wasn't working as expected. Derp...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use Python with [lxml](http://lxml.de/index.html) and I have to check if delta is greater than epsilon to get appropriate elements:

```
/root/row/checks[sum(./selections/tax/text()) - ./taxAmount/text() > 1e-6 or sum(./selections/tax/text()) - ./taxAmount/text() < -1e-6]
```

Sadly, XPath 1.0 (libxml2 doesn't support newer versions) doesn't have `abs()` function, so we have to use `or`.

Equality check doesn't work for me:

```
>>> tree.xpath('sum((//checks)[1]/selections/tax/text())')
4.140000000000001

>>> tree.xpath('sum((//checks)[1]/selections/tax/text()) - (//checks)[1]/taxAmount/text()')
8.881784197001252e-16
```